# Getting an error: "Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3"

Tags: swift, xcode

I just downloaded the new Xcode and updated my OSX. Again the error is:
"Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.3"
The line is:

```
import Canvas
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need a copy of the module that was compiler under Swift 3.2.3 if you wish to use it in your Swift 3.2.3 project. Either way, Swift 3 is already dated. Try to upgrade bother to Swift 4.

Comment: Hey I'm sort of new to programming. How do you a module and what's the best way to upgrade to swift 4?

Comment: Well, how did you obtain the current Canvas module you're using?

Comment: I think it's from this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPVKV4DXggs

Comment: Should I just reinstall cocoapods and Canvas??

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cocoapods, but there is almost certainly someway to specify what version you would like it to pull for you

Comment: Specify what version of Canvas or cocoapods?

Comment: Specify to Cocoapods what version of Canvas it should pull for you